# Is this property always or never satisfied when $R=N$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, logic, solution-verification, products

Let $N$ be a countable set and let $Z$ be an arbitrary set with arbitrary elements $i\in N$ and $z\in Z$. Then, for each $i\in N$, define some set $M_i$. Further, for each $R\subseteq N$, let $M_R=\prod_{i\in R}M_i$ be the Cartesian product of all sets $M_i$ satisfying $i\in R$.

Given any $R\subseteq N$, let $m_R$ be any arbitrary element of $M_R$, and let $R^c=N\backslash R$ be its complement. Further, let $f:M_N\to Z$ be a function, and let $o$ be some well-defined object. Last, fix some $z^*\in Z$.

Then, object $o$ satisfies **Property P** if for each set $R\subseteq N$ and every vector $m_R\in M_R$, there exists some vector $m_{R^c}\in M_{R^c}$ for which $f(m_R,m_{R^c})=z^*$. Formally,
\begin{gather}
(\forall R\subseteq N)(\forall m_R\in M_R)(\exists m_{R^c}\in M_{R^c})(f(m_R,m_{R^c})=z^*)
\end{gather}

*I do not know whether **Property P** is vacuously satisfied when $R=N$, or whether **Property P** is never satisfied when $R=N$.*

Let me try to explain my reasoning:

If $R=N$, then $R^c=N\backslash R=N\backslash N=N^c=\emptyset$, thus implying that $M_{R^c}=\emptyset$. Therefore, there exists no $m_{N^c}\in M_{N^c}$ satisfying $f(m_N,m_{N^c})=z^*$. By the same token, though, $f(m_N,m_{N^c})$ satisfies any condition I want to impose on it for all $m_{N^c}\in M_{N^c}$.

Can anybody help me see why I'm reaching two contradictory conclusions?

Comment: $R$ is bound in Property P. You mean you're looking at the part of the formula which follows $(\forall R \subseteq N)$?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, I don't understand what you mean by "R is bound in Property P". Could you please elaborate? Roughly, what I want to check is whether all objects fail to satisfy the formula because it imposes an impossible restriction for the case in which $R=N$.

Comment: Right, so you're asking whether $(\forall m_R \in M_R)(\exists m_{R^c} \in M_{R^c})(f(m_R, m_{R^c}) = z^{*})$ is true when $R=N$. Which is a piece of Property P, but doesn't say that P is satisfied or not, since P needs to consider all the subsets $R$.

Comment: You're right. I see your point now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You state that $R = N$ implies $M_{R^C} = M_{\emptyset} = \emptyset$. However the empty cartesian product is not empty. The usual definition of the cartesian product in set theory gives $M_{\emptyset} = \{ \emptyset \}$. So the condition is neither vacuously satisfied nor false in general. The condition just states that $f(m_N,\emptyset)=z^{*}$.

Comment: Given the expressions $f(m_R, m_{R^c})$, the domain of $f$ has to include the tuples of values from each $M_i$. $M$ was never defined, but I think it makes sense to say the domain of $f$ is $M_N$. Then the single element of $M_\emptyset$ is the zero-tuple, which we might write as $()$ rather than $\emptyset$ though $()$ is a bit confusing.

Comment: Thank you both for the answer and the comment. However, I do not see why $M_\emptyset=\{\emptyset\}$ nor why we should be able to define $f(m_N,\emptyset)$ when the domain of $f$ is simply $M_N$. Also, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2241536/what-is-cartesian-product-for-two-empty-sets#2241542

Comment: @Hector The link you give illustrates that the cartesion product is empty when one of the **factors** is empty. What you have in your question is a product over an empty **index set** (the product over an empty index set has one element, what this element is depends on your definition of the cartesian product). That is something completely different. An analogy with numbers: A product of some integers is $0$ if some factor is $0$. A product over no numbers is $1$.

Comment: @leon.fuchsler Thank you again for your useful clarification: I get your point now. Let me, please, enquire a bit further. Suppose now that $f(M_N)=z'$, where $z'\neq z^*$. Then, could I say that **Property P** fails to be satisfied? Similarly, if $f(M_N)=z^*$, could I say that **Property P** is satisfied (assuming, of course, that the equation is satisfied for all other $R\subset N$)?

Comment: @Hector You are being careless with the domain of $f$. The function takes two arguments and both are elements of some $M_R$ for a $R \subset N$. I think what you mean is this: If you find some $R \subset N$ and find $x \in M_R$ such that for all elements $y \in M_{R^c}$ we have $f(x,y) \neq z^{*}$, then the property is not satisfied.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I see it now.